# My Toggle Button doesn't get enabled when All other Switch Buttons are Ticked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see in my included [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alachgar/q2naydfw/14/) here, I am trying to enable a Toggle Button after ticking all other Toggle/switches on, it is definitely working with a Simple Submit Button show there, but not so much with a Toggle that says Pending/Done (Pending(Orange color), (Done(Green color).
Any Help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).on("change keyup", ".required", function(e) {
  let Disabled = $(".required").length;
  $(".required").each(function() {
    if (this.checked) Disabled--;
  });

  if (Disabled) {
    $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap5-toggle@5.0.6/css/bootstrap5-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap5-toggle@5.0.6/js/bootstrap5-toggle.ecmas.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.7/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.7/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

</head>
<div class="container">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Gmail</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Pika</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Justice</label>
      </div>
      <!--A Simple Submit Works Fine -->
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <button type="button" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div><br>
    <!--Toggle button doesn't work -->
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-disabled" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-onlabel="Done" data-offlabel="Pending" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="warning" disabled>

</form>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. You may not need the JSFiddle link now

Comment: I appreciate it @chris Barr But it doesn't show the Orange Toggle Button that I am trying to get help with .. the Normal Submit oand/or checkbox works fine as you can see... it's the Toggle/switch that doesn't for some reasons..

Comment: The links to your CSS and JS files have spaces/line breaks in them and they are causing 404 errors. Someone has suggested that edit, and I have approved it, but it needs more votes. Or you can fix that yourself since it's your question

Comment: I just tried it 
https://jsfiddle.net/alachgar/q2naydfw/14/
It works fine on my end !! I tried it on Edge and Firefox without logging in, no 404 ? are can you confirm again plese ?!!

Comment: I am talking about here on StackOverflow.  For simple demos you do not need to link people to an external website like JSFiddle. StackOverflow has snippets built in.  Please  [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/77484959/edit) to remove the extra spaces/lines from the linked files and the snippet in this question will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed [@chris-barr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79677/chris-barr) edit to show your orange switch. Sorry but I don't have reputation to post comment.

Your problem is how you dynamically enable/disable the `.toggle-disabled`
Here is how

```js
$(document).on("change keyup", ".required", function(e) {
  let Disabled = $(".required").length;
  $(".required").each(function() {
    if (this.checked) Disabled--;
  });

  if (Disabled) {
    $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".toggle-disabled")["1"].bootstrapToggle('disable');
  } else {
    $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".toggle-disabled")["1"].bootstrapToggle('enable');
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap5-toggle@5.0.6/css/bootstrap5-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap5-toggle@5.0.6/js/bootstrap5-toggle.ecmas.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.7/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.7/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

</head>
<div class="container">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Gmail</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Pika</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Justice</label>
      </div>
      <!--A Simple Submit Works Fine -->
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <button type="button" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div><br>
    <!--Toggle button doesn't work -->
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-disabled" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-onlabel="Done" data-offlabel="Pending" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="warning" disabled>
</form>
</div>
```

You need to use these to actually enable/disable them

```js
// To disable
$(".toggle-disabled")["1"].bootstrapToggle('disable');
// To enable
$(".toggle-disabled")["1"].bootstrapToggle('disable');
```

Because `Bootstrap Toggle` will insert their actual component next to your input. So modify your `input` disable property won't modify `Bootstrap Toggle`

Comment: Wonderful ! Thank you @duckstery, much appreciated !

Comment: I am sorry but the whole thing breaks when i remove the Submit button section which I didn't need, it was just there to show that the Submit works.
Is there a way to make it work just with the toggle ? I tried to modify my Script, no luck.

Comment: If you remove the submit button, try to fix the index from `["1"]` to `["0"]`. `$(".toggle-disabled")` will get all element that has class `toggle-disabled`. You have 2 tag that have that class (which submit button is the first one). So now when you remove it, there'll be no `["1"]` in the selected tag

Comment: Thank you that worked  so far i appreciate your prompt reply.

Comment: Now when I include my php cde the Status button doesn't get enabled anymore... it works until right after I add 
</tr><?php } ?> then it breaks ! any thoughts ? Thank you .